# Fonts only appear on the canvas after previous use of them in the page

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I have installed some fonts in the page like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Amsterdam Graffiti;
  src: url("./fonts/amsterdam.ttf");
}
```

and the fonts show up in the webpage pretty well.

The problem is: this page also has a canvas and when I write on it with the installed fonts, only the ones used in the webpage show up (the others are substituted by system fonts).

Example: in this following page, only 2 of 3 fonts are going to work on the canvas.

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function(){
var fontprevcanvas = document.getElementById("fontprevcanvas");
var ctx = fontprevcanvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.font='28px Amsterdam Graffiti';
ctx.textAlign = "center"; 
ctx.fillText('test1', 40, 40);

ctx.font='28px Army Rust';
ctx.textAlign = "center"; 
ctx.fillText('test2', 40, 80);

ctx.font='28px Badaboom BB';
ctx.textAlign = "center"; 
ctx.fillText('test3', 40, 120);
};
```

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Amsterdam Graffiti;
  src: url("./fonts/amsterdam.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Army Rust;
  src: url('./fonts/ARMY RUST.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Badaboom BB;
  src: url('./fonts/BADABB__.TTF');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a style="font-family: Amsterdam Graffiti; ">part of the body</a>
<a style="font-family: Army Rust; ">part of the body</a>

<canvas id="fontprevcanvas" width="180" height="180" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

this is the result:
[image: result_one]

But then, if I use the 3rd font in an element of the page, it finally shows up in the canvas:

**new HTML:**

```
<a style="font-family: Amsterdam Graffiti; ">part of the body</a>
<a style="font-family: Army Rust; ">part of the body</a>
<a style="font-family: Badaboom BB; ">part of the body</a>

<canvas id="fontprevcanvas" width="180" height="180" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Result:
[image: result_two]

As a workaround, I'm using the fonts in hidden elements of the page (it don't works with `display:none` too) like this:

```
<a style="font-family: Amsterdam Graffiti; visibility: hidden;">.</a>
<a style="font-family: Traveling Typewriter; visibility: hidden;">.</a>
<a style="font-family: Army Rust; visibility: hidden;">.</a>
<a style="font-family: Badaboom BB; visibility: hidden;">.</a>
<a style="font-family: Carnivalee Freakshow; visibility: hidden;">.</a>
<a style="font-family: Chinese Rocks; visibility: hidden;">.</a>
<a style="font-family: Cloister Black; visibility: hidden;">.</a>
<a style="font-family: Code; visibility: hidden;">.</a>
<a style="font-family: Hand of Sean; visibility: hidden;">.</a>
<a style="font-family: Ringbearer; visibility: hidden;">.</a>
```

But it don't seems like the best practice. **How can I use installed fonts in the canvas without to add it on elements of my webpage?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, browsers will only load fonts if they dimmed necessary to do so, i.e if there have some active elements that do use it.

Now, in supporting browsers (i.e all but MS), you can use the [CSS Font Loading API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API) to be able to better control how and when these fonts are loaded:

```js
if(window.FontFace) {
  // first declare our font-face
  const fontFace = new FontFace(
    'Shadows Into Light',
    "local('Shadows Into Light'), local('ShadowsIntoLight'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/shadowsintolight/v7/UqyNK9UOIntux_czAvDQx_ZcHqZXBNQzdcD55TecYQ.woff2) format('woff2')"
  );
  // add it to the list of fonts our document supports
  document.fonts.add(fontFace);
  // load the font
  fontFace.load()
    .then(draw);
}
else {
  console.log('fallback to some dummy element in the doc');
}

function draw() {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = "30px 'Shadows Into Light'";
  ctx.fillText("my text", 40, 40);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I wonder if this method you're using is the same as this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font looks very similar, but in the link it says that it is compatible with every browser even Microsoft ones (of course not with .woff2 font because their browsers can't handle this kind of font). Maybe this content can improve your answer somehow.

Comment: @Le____ yes that's the samr FontFace, but nope, what they say is supported by IE is the context.font property, they don't talk about supporting FontFace in this page